# RubyMine, run tests tags only

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, rubymine

example:
several scenarios with different tags like @slow, @fast, @regression.

Is there a way to run @regression scripts only via RubyMine like via command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the 'run' menu, then open 'edit configurations', you can set some default settings for cucumber (in the left hand column/tree view).

In the runner options setting, you can put '--tags @slow' etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many Run/Debug Configurations as you want.

1. Select Edit Configurations in the top menu:

[image]

2. Create Cucumber configuration you want:

[image]

3. PROFIT!

Now you can use any of created Run/Debug configuration with specified tags